# Is it reasonable to use SEH to protect my code from exceptions thrown by third party COM objects

Tags: windows, exception, com, seh

I'm protecting my own C++ code (Windows x86) from exceptions in a third party COM object and logging those exceptions using the following SEH pseudocode.

```
__try {
    hr = m_ComObj->SomeFunc();
} __except ( LogExceptionInfo(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()) ) {
    hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
    m_ComObjCrashed = true;
}
```

Is this approach likely to catch exceptions that would be handled if the SEH code wasn't present?

An MSDN article below mentions that the default unhandled exception filter will catch and fix the case where code writes to memory in loaded resources. Are there other cases where using SEH will interfere with desirable default OS behaviour?

[A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx)

Comment: Um, how do you know that the exception is recoverable? Maybe a critical section got orphaned, or the exception was caused by memory corruption.

Comment: Good point. I'm not continuing normal execution after the exception, just using it as a more graceful form of failure and logging some crash information in the filter function (the third party COM object contains anti-debugging code that stops MiniDumpWriteDump from working).

Comment: cf my previous question re the motivation for using SEH for logging crash information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977545/how-to-debug-a-crash-in-a-process-containing-anti-debugger-measures

Comment: But after your filter function logs the crash information, the program resumes execution. That will most likely lead to even worse (and more confusing) crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's quite reasonable.

It will catch all exceptions that are unhandled in the COM function

I don't see any interference-related problems with default OS behaviour

Comment: The default unhandled exception filter does the following (pasted from the link above). I was concerned that using my own SEH handling will disable this behaviour and wondered what else it might change.

"If the exception occurred because a resource section (.rsrc) of an EXE or DLL was written to, _BasepCurrentTopLevelFilter changes the faulting page's attributes from its normal read-only state, thereby allowing the write to occur. If this particular scenario occurs, UnhandledExceptionFilter returns EXCEPTION_ CONTINUE_EXECUTION and execution restarts at the faulting instruction."